# Finding the longest stretch of repeated words in a long string of characters

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, character

I have a long DNA sequence text file with characters (ATCG). I am looking for some method in R that can be used to find the longest stretch with repeated words. Lets say my string looks like,
AAGTGCGGGTTCAGATCGCCCCCCCATCGGGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCGA

I need the output possibly with counts,
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
n=16

Please help me with this.

Comment: Loop over all characters always keeping track of the previous character. Always compare previous with current character and if they match increase `sequenceLength` counter, if they don't reset `sequenceLength` counter. Or, keep track of start and end index of the longest sequence and update that. This way you know where you have found the longest sequence

Comment: do you only have one string or many strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have one string:

```
library(tidyverse)
string <- "AAGTGCGGGTTCAGATCGCCCCCCCATCGGGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCGA"

x <- str_extract_all(string, "(.)\\1+")
x[which.max(nchar(x))]

[1] "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

if you have many strings:

```
str_extract_all(c(string, string), "(.)\\1+")%>%
  map_chr(~.x[which.max(nchar(.x))])

[1] "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

To find the counts, just use `nchar` or even `str_count` of the result

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

s <- "AAGTGCGGGTTCAGATCGCCCCCCCATCGGGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCGA"

data.frame(seq = str_extract_all(s, "([A-Z])\\1{2,}") %>% unlist) %>% 
  mutate(n = str_count(seq)) %>% 
  slice_max(n, n = 1)

#>                seq  n
#> 1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 16
```

Answer (score 2):

First form a vector of all same base pair substrings.  Then, find the longest string in that vector.

```r
x <- "AAGTGCGGGTTCAGATCGCCCCCCCATCGGGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCGA"
parts <- unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=([ACGT]))(?!\\1)"))
parts[order(-nchar(parts), parts)][1]

[1] "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this

```
> s <- "AAGTGCGGGTTCAGATCGCCCCCCCATCGGGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATCGA"

> v <- regmatches(s, gregexpr("(.)\\1+", s))[[1]]

> v[which.max(nchar(v))]
[1] "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```